# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of null | HTML |JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an Html page with cards for my memory card game, The user is supposed to match a pair of cards and win an offer mentioned in the card. The offers are for an online grocery shopping application. I get the following error when I flip the card.

```
<div class="deck" id="iPad_Card_layout">
    <img id="shelfs" src="shelfs.png" srcset="shelfs.png 1x, shelfs@2x.png 2x">
    <div id="Repeat_Grid_5">
        <div id="Repeat_Grid_5_0" class="offers"> <!--onclick="application.goToTargetView(event)"-->
            <div id="card" class="card" data-framework="matchcard">
                <div class="card-back card-face">
                    <svg class="Rectangle_13">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_13" rx="8" ry="8" x="0" y="0" width="141" height="172">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <svg class="Rectangle_1">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_1" rx="32" ry="32" x="0" y="0" width="64" height="64">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <div id="logo" class="logo">
                        <img id="shopping-cart" src="shopping-cart.png" srcset="shopping-cart.png 1x, shopping-cart@2x.png 2x">

                        <div id="Joeys">
                            <span>Joey’s</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="win_card" class=" card-front card-face">
                    <svg class="Rectangle_31">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_31" rx="8" ry="8" x="0" y="0" width="140" height="171">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <img class="match-value" id="softdrinks" src="softdrinks.png" srcset="softdrinks.png 1x, softdrinks@2x.png 2x">

                    <div id="ID25__OFF_on__Soft_Drinks">
                        <span>25 % OFF on <br/>Soft Drinks</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Repeat_Grid_5_1" class="offers">
            <div id="card" class="card "data-framework="matchcard">
                <div class="card-back card-face">
                    <svg class="Rectangle_13">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_13" rx="8" ry="8" x="0" y="0" width="141" height="172">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <svg class="Rectangle_1">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_1" rx="32" ry="32" x="0" y="0" width="64" height="64">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <div id="logo" class="logo">
                        <img id="shopping-cart" src="shopping-cart.png" srcset="shopping-cart.png 1x, shopping-cart@2x.png 2x">

                        <div id="Joeys">
                            <span>Joey’s</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="win_card" class=" card-front card-face">
                    <svg class="Rectangle_31">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_31" rx="8" ry="8" x="0" y="0" width="140" height="171">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <img id="vegetables" class="match-value" src="vegetables.png" srcset="vegetables.png 1x, vegetables@2x.png 2x">

                    <div id="ID10__OFF_on__fruits_veg">
                        <span>10 % OFF on <br/>Fruits <br>&<br> Vegetables</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Repeat_Grid_5_2" class="offers">
            <div id="card" class="card" data-framework="matchcard">
                <div class="card-back card-face">
                    <svg class="Rectangle_13">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_13" rx="8" ry="8" x="0" y="0" width="141" height="172">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <svg class="Rectangle_1">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_1" rx="32" ry="32" x="0" y="0" width="64" height="64">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <div id="logo" class="logo">
                        <img id="shopping-cart" src="shopping-cart.png" srcset="shopping-cart.png 1x, shopping-cart@2x.png 2x">

                        <div id="Joeys">
                            <span>Joey’s</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="win_card" class=" card-front card-face">
                    <svg class="Rectangle_31">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_31" rx="8" ry="8" x="0" y="0" width="140" height="171">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <img id="softdrinks"  class="match-value" src="softdrinks.png" srcset="softdrinks.png 1x, softdrinks@2x.png 2x">

                    <div id="ID25__OFF_on__Soft_Drinks">
                        <span>25 % OFF on <br/>Soft Drinks</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Repeat_Grid_5_3" class="offers">
            <div id="card" class="card " data-framework="matchcard">
                <div class="card-back card-face">
                    <svg class="Rectangle_13">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_13" rx="8" ry="8" x="0" y="0" width="141" height="172">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <svg class="Rectangle_1">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_1" rx="32" ry="32" x="0" y="0" width="64" height="64">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <div id="logo" class="logo">
                        <img id="shopping-cart" src="shopping-cart.png" srcset="shopping-cart.png 1x, shopping-cart@2x.png 2x">

                        <div id="Joeys">
                            <span>Joey’s</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="win_card" class=" card-front card-face">
                    <svg class="Rectangle_31">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_31" rx="8" ry="8" x="0" y="0" width="140" height="171">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <img id="vegetables" class="match-value"  src="vegetables.png" srcset="vegetables.png 1x, vegetables@2x.png 2x">

                    <div id="ID10__OFF_on__fruits_veg">
                        <span>10 % OFF on <br/>Fruits <br>&<br> Vegetables</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Repeat_Grid_5_4" class="offers">
            <div id="card" class="card " data-framework="matchcard">
                <div class="card-back card-face">
                    <svg class="Rectangle_13">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_13" rx="8" ry="8" x="0" y="0" width="141" height="172">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <svg class="Rectangle_1">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_1" rx="32" ry="32" x="0" y="0" width="64" height="64">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <div id="logo" class="logo">
                        <img id="shopping-cart" src="shopping-cart.png" srcset="shopping-cart.png 1x, shopping-cart@2x.png 2x">

                        <div id="Joeys">
                            <span>Joey’s</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="win_card" class=" card-front card-face">
                    <svg class="Rectangle_31">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_31" rx="8" ry="8" x="0" y="0" width="140" height="171">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <img id="dairy_items" class="match-value"  src="dairy_items.png" srcset="dairy_items.png 1x, dairy_items@2x.png 2x">

                    <div id="ID15__OFF_on__Dairy_items">
                        <span>15 % OFF on <br/>Dairy Products</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Repeat_Grid_5_5" class="offers">
            <div id="card" class="card " data-framework="matchcard">
                <div class="card-back card-face">
                    <svg class="Rectangle_13">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_13" rx="8" ry="8" x="0" y="0" width="141" height="172">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <svg class="Rectangle_1">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_1" rx="32" ry="32" x="0" y="0" width="64" height="64">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <div id="logo" class="logo">
                        <img id="shopping-cart" src="shopping-cart.png" srcset="shopping-cart.png 1x, shopping-cart@2x.png 2x">

                        <div id="Joeys">
                            <span>Joey’s</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="win_card" class=" card-front card-face">
                    <svg class="Rectangle_31">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_31" rx="8" ry="8" x="0" y="0" width="140" height="171">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <img id="dairy_items" class="match-value" src="dairy_items.png" srcset="dairy_items.png 1x, dairy_items@2x.png 2x">

                    <div id="ID15__OFF_on__Dairy_items">
                        <span>15 % OFF on <br/>Dairy Products</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Repeat_Grid_5_6" class="offers">
            <div id="card" class="card " data-framework="matchcard">
                <div class="card-back card-face">
                    <svg class="Rectangle_13">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_13" rx="8" ry="8" x="0" y="0" width="141" height="172">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <svg class="Rectangle_1">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_1" rx="32" ry="32" x="0" y="0" width="64" height="64">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <div id="logo" class="logo">
                        <img id="shopping-cart"  src="shopping-cart.png" srcset="shopping-cart.png 1x, shopping-cart@2x.png 2x">

                        <div id="Joeys">
                            <span>Joey’s</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="win_card" class=" card-front card-face">
                    <svg class="Rectangle_31">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_31" rx="8" ry="8" x="0" y="0" width="140" height="171">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <img id="pringles_offer" class="match-value" src="pringles_offer.png" srcset="pringles_offer.png 1x, pringles_offer@2x.png 2x">

                    <div id="IDBuy_one_get_free">
                        <span>Buy any can of <br/>Pringles and get <br>another for <b>FREE!</b></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Repeat_Grid_5_7" class="offers">
            <div id="card" class="card " data-framework="matchcard">
                <div class="card-back card-face">
                    <svg class="Rectangle_13">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_13" rx="8" ry="8" x="0" y="0" width="141" height="172">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <svg class="Rectangle_1">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_1" rx="32" ry="32" x="0" y="0" width="64" height="64">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <div id="logo" class="logo">
                        <img id="shopping-cart" src="shopping-cart.png" srcset="shopping-cart.png 1x, shopping-cart@2x.png 2x">

                        <div id="Joeys">
                            <span>Joey’s</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="win_card" class=" card-front card-face">
                    <svg class="Rectangle_31">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_31" rx="8" ry="8" x="0" y="0" width="140" height="171">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <img id="pringles_offer" class="match-value"  src="pringles_offer.png" srcset="pringles_offer.png 1x, pringles_offer@2x.png 2x">

                    <div id="IDBuy_one_get_free">
                        <span>Buy any can of <br/>Pringles and get <br>another for <b>FREE!</b></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Repeat_Grid_5_8" class="offers">
            <div id="card" class="card " data-framework="matchcard">
                <div class="card-back card-face">
                    <svg class="Rectangle_13">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_13" rx="8" ry="8" x="0" y="0" width="141" height="172">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <svg class="Rectangle_1">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_1" rx="32" ry="32" x="0" y="0" width="64" height="64">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <div id="logo" class="logo">
                        <img id="shopping-cart" src="shopping-cart.png" srcset="shopping-cart.png 1x, shopping-cart@2x.png 2x">

                        <div id="Joeys">
                            <span>Joey’s</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="win_card" class=" card-front card-face">
                    <svg class="Rectangle_31">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_31" rx="8" ry="8" x="0" y="0" width="140" height="171">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <img id="oreo" class="match-value" src="oreo_offer.png" srcset="oreo_offer.png 1x, oreo_offer@2x.png 2x">

                    <div id="IDOreo_offer">
                        <span>Oreo Party Pack<br/>for only <br/>Rs.1500.00</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Repeat_Grid_5_9" class="offers">
            <div id="card" class="card " data-framework="matchcard">
                <div class="card-back card-face">
                    <svg class="Rectangle_13">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_13" rx="8" ry="8" x="0" y="0" width="141" height="172">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <svg class="Rectangle_1">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_1" rx="32" ry="32" x="0" y="0" width="64" height="64">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <div id="logo" class="logo">
                        <img id="shopping-cart" src="shopping-cart.png" srcset="shopping-cart.png 1x, shopping-cart@2x.png 2x">

                        <div id="Joeys">
                            <span>Joey’s</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="win_card" class=" card-front card-face">
                    <svg class="Rectangle_31">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_31" rx="8" ry="8" x="0" y="0" width="140" height="171">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <img id="oreo" class="match-value" src="oreo_offer.png" srcset="oreo_offer.png 1x, oreo_offer@2x.png 2x">

                    <div id="IDOreo_offer">
                        <span>Oreo Party Pack<br/>for only <br/>Rs.1500.00</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Repeat_Grid_5_10" class="offers">
            <div id="card" class="card " data-framework="matchcard">
                <div class="card-back card-face">
                    <svg class="Rectangle_13">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_13" rx="8" ry="8" x="0" y="0" width="141" height="172">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <svg class="Rectangle_1">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_1" rx="32" ry="32" x="0" y="0" width="64" height="64">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <div id="logo" class="logo">
                        <img id="shopping-cart" src="shopping-cart.png" srcset="shopping-cart.png 1x, shopping-cart@2x.png 2x">

                        <div id="Joeys">
                            <span>Joey’s</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="win_card" class=" card-front card-face">
                    <svg class="Rectangle_31">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_31" rx="8" ry="8" x="0" y="0" width="140" height="171">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <img id="dilmah" class="match-value" src="dilmah_offer.png" srcset="dilmah_offer.png 1x, dilmah_offer@2x.png 2x">

                    <div id="IDdilamah_offer">
                        <span>Get a Free Pack <br>of Dilmah tea <br>of your choice.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Repeat_Grid_5_11" class="offers">
            <div id="card" class="card " data-framework="matchcard">
                <div class="card-back card-face">
                    <svg class="Rectangle_13">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_13" rx="8" ry="8" x="0" y="0" width="141" height="172">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <svg class="Rectangle_1">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_1" rx="32" ry="32" x="0" y="0" width="64" height="64">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <div id="logo" class="logo">
                        <img id="shopping-cart" src="shopping-cart.png" srcset="shopping-cart.png 1x, shopping-cart@2x.png 2x">

                        <div id="Joeys">
                            <span>Joey’s</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="win_card" class=" card-front card-face">
                    <svg class="Rectangle_31">
                        <rect id="Rectangle_31" rx="8" ry="8" x="0" y="0" width="140" height="171">
                        </rect>
                    </svg>
                    <img id="dilmah" class="match-value" src="dilmah_offer.png" srcset="dilmah_offer.png 1x, dilmah_offer@2x.png 2x">

                    <div id="IDdilamah_offer">
                        <span>Get a Free Pack <br>of Dilmah tea <br>of your choice.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the script to flip the cards and see if they are matched is in the script.js file

```
class AudioController{
    constructor() {
        this.flipSound = new Audio('Assets/audio/flip.wav');
        this.matchSound = new Audio('Assets/audio/match.wav');

    }
    flip(){
        this.flipSound.play();
    }
    match(){
        this.matchSound.play();
    }
}
let hasFlippedCard = false;
let firstCard, secondCard;
class MixORMatch{
    constructor(totalChances,cards) {
        this.cardsArray = cards;
        this.totalChances = totalChances;
        this.chancesRemaining = totalChances;
        this.chances = document.getElementById('chances-remaining');
        this.audioController = new AudioController();

        //shuffle cards
        this.shuffleCards();


        //start game
        this.cardToCheck = null;
        this.totalClicks = 0;
        this.chancesRemaining = this.totalChances;
        this.matchedCards = [];




    }
    startGame(){
        this.cardToCheck = null;
        this.totalClicks = 0;
        this.chancesRemaining = this.totalChances;
        this.matchedCards = [];


    }

    flipCard(card) {
        if(this.canFlipCard(card)){
            this.audioController.flip();
            this.totalClicks++;
            card.classList.add('visible');

            //first click
            hasFlippedCard = true;
            firstCard = this;

            if (this.canFlipCard(card)){
                this.checkForCardMatch(card);
            }else{
                this.cardToCheck = card;
            }


        }else{
            //second click
            hasFlippedCard = false;
            secondCard = this;
            console.log("flipped")
        }
    }
    hideCards() {
        this.cardsArray.forEach(card=> {
            card.classList.remove('visible');
            card.classList.remove('matched');
        });
    }
    checkForCardMatch(card) {
        if (this.getCardType(card)===this.getCardType(this.cardToCheck)){
            this.cardMatch(card,this.cardToCheck);
        }else{
            this.cardMisMatch(card,this.cardToCheck);
        }
        this.cardToCheck = null;
    }
    cardMatch(card1,card2){
        this.matchedCards.push(card1);
        this.matchedCards.push(card2);
        card1.classList.add('matched');
        card2.classList.add('matched');
        this.audioController.match();
        if(this.matchedCards.length === this.cardsArray.length){
            console.log("win");
        }
    }

    cardMisMatch(card1,card2){
        setTimeout(()=>{
            card1.classList.remove('visible');
            card2.classList.remove('visible');
        },1000);
    }
    shuffleCards(cardsArray){
       let cardscount = cardsArray,length;
        for(let i =cardscount; i>0; i--){
            let randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
            cardsArray[randIndex].style.order = i;
            cardsArray[i].style.order = randIndex;
        }
    }


    getCardType(card){
        return card.getElementsByClassName('match-value')[0].src;
    }

    canFlipCard(card){
         return true;//(!this.busy && !this.matchedCards.includes(card) && card!== this.cardToCheck);
    }

}
function ready(){
    let cardDeck = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('deck'));
    let cards = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('card'));
    let game = new MixORMatch(3,cards);
   /* overlays.forEach(overlay => {
        overlay.addEventListener('click',()=>{
            overlay.classList.remove('visible');
            //game.startGame();
        });
    });*/

    cards.forEach(card =>{
        card.addEventListener('click',()=>{
            //flipping card game
            game.startGame();
            game.flipCard(card);

        });
    });
}

if(document.readyState === 'loading'){
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',ready);
}else{
    ready();
}
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error I have defined the cards to match class as "match-value" which is the image, I the get image src and check whether it matches the one the card user has flipped earlier. But when I flip both cards I get the above mentioned error. In the script in "getCardType".

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your `getCardType()` function. You wrote:

```
getCardType(card) {
    return card.getElementsByClassName('match-value')[0].src;
}
```

It should be:

```
getCardType(card){
    return document.getElementsByClassName('match-value')[0].src;
    //     ^--- you wrote 'card' here
}
```